# Angular reload issue

Tags: angular

How to force to refresh the page after redirecting one page to another page. When I try to use `location.reload` inside `ngOnInit()`. Page keeps refreshing.

the issue was created item is not updating in the DOM/Model until I refresh the page.

Any expert advice please.

Sample code link

[Angular 5 page reload data refresh not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456227/angular-5-page-reload-data-refresh-not-working/54458494#54458494)

Comment: Add hash to the end of the url... 

In ngOnInit, only reload if there is no hash at the end...

check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985507/one-time-page-refresh-after-first-page-load

Comment: Why would you reload?

Comment: data is not updating...

Comment: in that case debug why it's not updating. refreshing the page is a bad solution. use console.log to check if the data is loaded and check your template bindings.

Comment: Issue not reproducible in local. Only on production it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

When you reload the page Angular application is reloaded as well, your component is initialized, ngOnInit() method runs, you refresh the page and this process starts again.
It's not Angular-way to reload the page, you should perform all stuff without reloading.